# Angular-ui bootstrap modal button will not execute function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have my modal set up as so

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="myModalContent.html">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h3 class="modal-title">Confirm</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Are you sure you want to remove Two Factor Authentication from your profile?</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="removeSetting()">Yes</button>
        <button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="$dismiss()">Cancel</button>
    </div>
</script>
```

Hitting the cancel button does what it should, simply closes the modal. My problem comes when a user hits the yes button. My function `removeSetting()` never gets executed.

```
$scope.removeSetting = function() {
        TwoFactorAuthenticationService.removetAuthetication().then(function(data) {
            $scope.busy3=false;
            notifyService.alert("error", notifyService.getAlertText('2FactorRemovedToken'));
            $scope.busy=true;
            $timeout(function() {
                $scope.templateUrl = 'twofactorsetup/step1.html';
            }, 3000);
        }, function() {
            notifyService.alert("error", notifyService.getAlertText('2FactorRemoveTokenFailed'));
        });
    };
```

That is the function that should be called and executed. What am I missing?

Comment: Is that function gets hit or not? did you place any `debugger` and see?

Comment: is function in scope (try to display removeSetting variable in templa)
if is in scope, does it enter it (add log on beginning) - there can be eg. some problem in promise or missing $apply around result function. Hard to guess

Comment: How did you open your modal ? Which controller you gave in your modal ? Is the function on it ?

Answer (score 0):

Place code like this in modal initialize

```
$modal.open({
    templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
    scope: $scope,
    controller: function($scope, $modalInstance) {
        $scope.removeSetting = function() {
            //place your code here or call function from parent scope
            $scope.$parent.removeSetting();
            $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
        };
    }
});
```

You don't need scope parameter if not using parent scope.

Or you can use call function from parent scope from template like this (by using $parent.removeSetting() call)

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="myModalContent.html">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h3 class="modal-title">Confirm</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Are you sure you want to remove Two Factor Authentication from your profile?</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="$parent.removeSetting()">Yes</button>
        <button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="$dismiss()">Cancel</button>
    </div>
</script>
```